# Will restarting the system flush BIND (named) cache?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, gnu

Will restarting the system flush BIND (named) cache? I use GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

yes it will; but you dont have to reboot the server; try:

```
rndc flush
```

or just restart bind

Comment: Thanks. But actually, I did not want it to flush cache on restart. In fact I wanted it to keep the cache as long as possible, unless I said `rndc flush`. :-)

Comment: Is there an option to prevent flushing cache on restart?

Comment: @Akilan - you can dump current cache with rndc dumpdb ; but i dont think it's possible to reload such data [ see here https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2002-November/042297.html ]